# Unable to connect to Amazon RDS from EC2 Wordpress during setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have setup an RDS MySQL instance on Amazon RDS which will be accessed through EC2. When I enter my database details to WordPress setup and proceed with the installation, it returns with an error saying "Error establishing a database connection".

I thought this is because the Security Group of the database instance is not allowing the inbound traffic for EC2. Then I added the Security Group of my EC2 instance to the inbound rules of RDS instance's Security Group. Still the same issue.

Allowing **All traffic** also did not resolve the problem.

Although I found some people have encountered with similar problems, I could not resolve this problem with the suggested answers.

[image: Error message]

I appreciate if someone could help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

This could result from so many reasons. It would be hard to give you a short answer.

First of all, did you check that the username and password are correct? Can you connect from elsewhere?

Secondly, security groups are not always enough. There could be a problem with network routing or ACLs. In order to verify that there is indeed connectivity between your EC2 instance and the RDS instance, run this from the EC2 instance:

`nc -vz RDS_HOSTNAME 5432`

Where `RDS_HOSTNAME` is the RDS instance endpoint. You should receive a message that the connection was successful.

Comment: I managed to connect to the database from MySQL Workbench. However, Ncat returned with "Connection timeout." message. Anything I can do to resolve the routing?

Comment: Read this: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/instance-vpc-troubleshoot/

Comment: Followed the steps in this link. Everything is the same as the suggested here. But still unable to connect.